# Category Layout Update - Custom Product List Template

Tags: magento2, category, template, product-list, layout-update

I'm trying to apply an XML Layout Update to a small selection of categories to have a custom product listing design. All other categories need to remain as-is so I cannot simply globally change the product list template for all categories.

I have already made various attempts to do this including (Where `Namespace_Module` is my own module with a `list.phtml`)

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list" template="Namespace_Module::list.phtml" />
```

and

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">%Namespace_Module::list.phtml%</argument>
    </arguments>
</referenceBlock>
```

Is there any restriction on overriding certain blocks? I can't see what is wrong with the above for this not to work?

To confirm, I'm applying this in the **Category > Layout Update XML** as that is the only place I can do it dynamically for a range of categories

**I'm running Magento v2.1.3**

Comment: Have u tried  Layout Update XML?

Comment: Yes, I might not have made it clear in my question but this is the only place I have (and can) apply this (Category -> Layout Update XML) because I want to apply this to a selection of categories

Comment: @Turv this part works for Config: `Category -> Layout Update XML` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look the source code of Magento 2.1.3 version, it used `<action method="setTemplate">`:

```
<referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
     <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">%Namespace_Module::list.phtml%</argument>
     </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Whilst I'm convinced I had attempted SetTemplate in the past this worked perfectly!

Comment: perfect. new to magento2. could you please tell where do the list.phtml file go?

Comment: Do you have a custom module? The `list.phtml` should put under template folder.